# Sierra installation not starting after download

Tags: install, macos

I have a MacBook Pro 2014 with El Capitan and I tried to upgrade to Sierra. It seems to have downloaded fine, but when I click on install, nothing happens.

In system log, I see the following message:

> 10/9/16 10:58:00.621 AM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.InstallAssistant.Sierra.338272[624]) Service exited due to signal: Killed: 9

Not sure what is going on.